# Spring UriComponentsBuilder add username:password via builder

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to construct a URL of the format `http://username:password@localhost` using the `UriComponentsBuilder`?

I've tried setting the `path` value with

```
.path(String.format("%s:%s@", getUsername(), getPassword()))
```

However, this just gets appended to the end of the URI when building.

(Headers and other authentication methods are not supported in the third-party application this is calling)

I'm thinking this isn't supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
      .scheme("http").host(String.format("%s:%s@", getUsername(), getPassword()))
```

Use the host method. The path method will always append to the end and also provide a path seperator `/` which you don't want